# Naming of PLA and PAL

Tags: programmable-logic

I am studying the Programmable Logic Array (PLA) and Programmable Array Logic (PAL). I understood every detail I found about them including the implementation and difference between them. But I have a very simple question about their naming.
Why did the early designer of such devices choose those close names for both of them? If the PLA appeared first then they designed a new device, why did they just swapped two words in the name from **Programmable *Logic Array*** (PLA) to **Programmable *Array Logic*** (PAL)? Do not you find it very confusing to differentiate between them?
I did google search to find an answer to this question but I did not find any.
Do you have any explanation?

Comment: It might just be a nuance you're missing if you're not a native English speaker. To me, they sound like distinctly different things even if I don't know exactly what the differences are. Not knowing exactly what the differences are between the two, PLA clearly sounds to me something like an FPGA or CPLD, whereas a PAL sounds like something different.

Comment: See https://www.computerhistory.org/siliconengine/pal-user-programmable-logic-devices-introduced/ for a short bit of the history.

Comment: Thank you @Toor, yes I am not a native speaker. Indeed I know that they are different two devices. But I am always confused which one is programmable and which is not. I cannot find any connection between the naming difference and the implementation difference.

Comment: Thank you @jonk, it is an interesting link. However, it does not answer my question about the naming.

Comment: That's why I didn't write it as an answer. I wasn't sure what exactly you wanted and if it was enough.

Comment: Thank you @jonk, it was a good chance to know this site to search about the history of any scientific topic. Mostly, history helps in understanding many concepts.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the link that @jonk put in a [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/432244/naming-of-pla-and-pal#comment1079185_432244): There are three ways to implement a generic programmable sum-of-products (AND gates followed by OR gates) function. In historical order, they are:

- **PROM** Programmable Read-Only Memory - the word decoder (AND gates) are fixed, and the data (OR gates) are programmable.
- **PLA** Programmable Logic Array - both the AND gates and the OR gates are programmable. This allows more complex functions than a straight PROM allows with a much more efficient implementation.
- **PAL** Programmable Array Logic - the AND gates are programmable, but the OR gates are fixed. It was realized that the PLA was overkill for many simple functions that only needed a limited number of product terms per output, so fixing the OR structure allowed a much smaller chip.

The similarity of the last two names is mainly a historical artifact, and also probably a function of how the devices were marketed.

Comment: Thank you @Dave for the summary. Till now, this is the most probable reason to be just naming for marketing.

Comment: A pity it isn't *Programmable **And** array Logic*.

Answer (score 1):

*Why did the designers of such devices choose those close names for both of them?*

My understanding at the time was it was **really just about different companies and in particular trademarks for extremely similar technologies**.  Linguistically, there's hardly any difference between adjective + countable noun "logic array" and the adjective + uncountable noun ("array logic").  It's a question of minor stress.  But there is potential an enormous economic difference if you can establish a valuable trademark.

Obviously it's true that there were the differences mentioned in the engineering, but basically they're the same thing, which slightly different restrictions in any given device.  You also have to remember that it was common for programmable chips to be in sockets, and that very many different PALs could go in the same socket: which mean you could adjust the OR gates by choosing a different part, and plug it in later. Not post-build programmable, but certainly post-build changeable.

In my firm we called all of them "programmable logic" without much distinction -- because the "array" feature was an implemntation detail.  And we'd choose whatever was the simplest, most available, or cheapest part for a given application.

You can see from MMI's explanation that both the PROM and the PAL can be considered a special cases of the fully-general PLA.

[image]
From [MMI Pal Handbook 3rd Ed (1983)](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/mmi/_dataBooks/1983_MMI_PAL_Handbook_3ed.pdf)